# can't delete all the elements in list when using remove() on python

Tags: python, list, element

```
users=['admin','tony','roger','lily']
if users:
    for user in users:
        users.remove(user)
print(users)
```

## I don't know why when I print users it still have element to print?

Comment: One does not simply change list size while iterating over it

Comment: modiying a list **as you loop through the exact same list** is not a good idea unless you are 100% certain what you are doing

Comment: also why not just overwrite the original one with an empty one instead? `users = []`

Comment: If you just want to clear the list, use `users.clear()`.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam actually it work's as it should

Comment: Thank you for all of yours useful comments, because I am a self learning beginner and I am solving a little quiz on book.